# How to highlight code parts that are longer than 80 chars?

Tags: emacs, highlighting, long-lines

In Emacs, I'd like to highlight the parts of long lines that exceed 80 characters.

The package `highlight-80+` is great for that. But how can I automatically enable it when a C++ source file is loaded?

I tried to add `highlight-80+` to the C++ mode, but it didn't work:

```lisp
(require 'highlight-80+)
(defun my-c++-mode-common-hook ()
  (highlight-80+-mode 1))
(add-hook 'c++-mode-common-hook 'my-c++-mode-common-hook)
```

When I load a .cc file it goes in C++ mode but `highlight-80+` is not enabled, so the long lines are not marked.

Comment: Frank, I think you are almost there. In last line of your code its not `C++-mode-common-hook` but `C++-mode-hook` or `c-mode-common-hook`

Answer (score 2):

Note that the [Highlight80Plus](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Highlight80Plus) wiki says that it is built-in to emacs starting with 23.  I believe it's referring to whitespace-mode; it does this and is built in to emacs.

There is a function in [emacs-starter-kit](https://github.com/technomancy/emacs-starter-kit/) that does something like this already but you could easily duplicate it,

```lisp
(defun esk-turn-on-whitespace ()
  (whitespace-mode t))

(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'esk-turn-on-whitespace)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```lisp
(autoload 'highlight-80+)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.cpp$" . highlight-80+-mode))
```

Comment: Thanks. But then it's not C++ mode anymore, but only highlight-80+ mode, as a major mode.

Comment: Sorry, can you try to `(add-hook...` after a `(eval-after-load "c++-mode"` ?

Comment: so it will look: `(eval-after-load "c++-mode" (add-hook 'c++-mode-common-hook 'my-c++-mode-common-hook))`

Comment: `eval-after-load` is not needed here because you can add to the symbol of any hook regardless of it exists yet. And: If you use `eval-after-load` you have to quote the form to be eval'ed then otherwise it will be eval'ed right away, thus `(eval-after-load "c++-mode" '(add-hook 'c++-mode-common-hook 'my-c++-mode-common-hook))`

Answer (score 1):

See the `whitespace-mode`, it does this kind of highlighting and more:

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WhiteSpace